# Checking calculation of covariance matrix in R

Tags: r, covariance-matrix

I came across this formula in a text that says $S$ is the sample covariance matrix where

$$S = \sum_{j=1}^n(\mathbf{X}_j - \bar{\mathbf{X}})(\mathbf{X}_j-\bar{\mathbf{X}})'$$, or from the source:

[image]

What I am trying to figutre out is how to calculate that equation in `R`. For example, if I had the following:

```
x <- c(1, 3, 5, 2)
y <- c(2, 3, 8, 7)
z <- c(22, 1, 3, 3)

X <- cbind(x, y, z)
```

I assume I can just use the `cov()` function and get

```
> cov(X)
           x          y         z
x   2.916667   3.333333 -11.25000
y   3.333333   8.666667 -17.66667
z -11.250000 -17.666667  97.58333
```

I also saw this calculation based on the above formula:

```
xbar <- apply(X, 2, mean)
d <- as.matrix(t(t(X) - xbar))

s2 <- matrix(0, 3, 3)
for (i in 1:3) {
  s2 <- s2 + (d[i, ]) %*% t(d[i, ])
}
> s2
            x     y        z
[1,]   8.1875  11.5 -36.9375
[2,]  11.5000  22.0 -44.5000
[3,] -36.9375 -44.5 274.6875
```

but as you can see, the two do not return the same sample covariance matrix. I am having a hard time figuring out which is the correct way to calculate that equation, or if neither is correct.

Comment: you did not divide by `3`. in your case, you do not need the for loop as you are already using the matrix multiplication function. Simply do: `t(d)%*%d/3` or you could directly do `crossprod(scale(X, T, F))/3`

Comment: @onyambu If I take my answer and divide by 3, I don't get the same answer as the cov() function. I.e., cov(X) does not equal s2 / 3

Comment: Use the code `t(d) %*% d/3` and not `s2/3` your s2 is incorrect

Comment: `all.equal(cov(X), t(d)%*%d/3)` returns `TRUE` meaning the division by 3 is correct

Comment: @Onyambu I see, thanks for the clarification. Something I realize is that the formula is not for the covariance, i.e., $S = \sum_{j=1}^n(\mathbf{X}_j - \bar{\mathbf{X}})(\mathbf{X}_j-\bar{\mathbf{X}})'$$. Is what I am calculating correct for this formula?

Comment: its unclear to me what you are computing. this seems to result in a vector and not a matrix

Comment: @Onyambu, I added an image of the formula for clarification.

Comment: @Onyambu, sorry if I am asking too much, but even just a formula for that equation is greatly appreciated.

Comment: huh thats still the covariance matrix. That is simply `t(d) %*%d`. or `cov(X)*3`

Comment: You should loop through the rows. ie `for(i in seq_len(nrow(X)))....` not `1:3`